# Key Benefits of MSMQ

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I have seen many socket application in which there is use of MSMQ. But when I go in details I think that we can do it without MSMQ also, so I want to know what is key benefit of MSMQ. Why should someone use MSMQ in his own application.

Comment: Are you asking why use MSMQ for queueing message rather than some other queueing mechanism, or why queue message rather than just passing them directly to the destination?

Comment: Some clues you can find here as well http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/254742-when-where-i-should-use-msmq

Answer (score 22, accepted):

MSMQ is a great piece of Windows. It is basically a [message-oriented middleware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-oriented_middleware) that helps a lot in some software architectures.

This mainly addresses the common use case of asynchronous message processing: you have a service `Service1` that communicates (send messages) with another part of your software architecture, say `Service2`.

Main problem: what if `Service2` becomes suddenly unavailable? Will messages be lost?
If you use MSMQ it won't: `Service1` will send messages into a queue, and `Service2` will dequeue when it is available.

MSMQ will resolve following common issues:

- temporary unavailability of a service: messages are persisted on the disk and will be dequeued when the service becomes available again, so **no messages are lost**
- as it's fully asynchronous, it'll help a lot in case of **punctual peak load**: your `Service2` won't die under the heavy load, it'll just dequeue and process messages, one after one

Pros of MSMQ vs another message-oriented middleware:

- free and built-in (shipped with Windows)
- light
- good integration with other Microsoft products (for instance there is the `System.Messaging` namespace in .Net to deal with MSMQ)
- monitoring capabilities (using perfmon counters: number of message received per second...)
- transactional queues
- persistence on disk so messages are never lost
- available through the network (remote queues)

Comment: What if MSMQ suddenly becomes unavailable ? don't we fall into the same trap ?

Comment: @ken2k To grant availability from both services should each of them have a MSMQ in the same server? So Service 2 would read from the MSMQ in the Service 1's server and vice versa?

Comment: this was a great answer, I can't see why @ken2k hasn't responded these comments.

Comment: Perhaps ken can elaborate more, but my failures of Service 2 (S2) could mean your service isn't necessarily "gone", but failing to process the items from Service 1 (S1) correctly. We always use queues and don't allow message deletion until completely processed. This way if we created a new version or something weird is happening we have a chance to respond before we lose pertinent data. 

Lose coupling is nice too.