# How to allow user update data to server even when database is down

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I am currently developing an asp.net mvc 4 application with .net 4.0.

A critical requirement is that I must allow for updates to be made to system even if Database is down (it could be down in night time, but some users still need to login and use the system).

I have never experienced this problem before and have no idea of how to do it? Or even is it possible?

Please give me some instructions or some tutorial links. I am really appreciated.

(I also did some researches, and found some tutorials about asynchronous controller in asp.net mvc. But I wonder if it can satisfy my requirement?)

Comment: You could queue your changes in local storage while the database is down, and persist the changes back to the database when it is up again

Comment: check the database connection, if not available, use file to store data and then insert into database when database is up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MSMQ to queue your requests to server and process them one by one.You need to make sure that this server never gets down.
More info at

[Key Benefits of MSMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077598/key-benefits-of-msmq)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723251.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But is there any other way? because i don't prefer MSMQ. Can I use asynchronous controller in asp.net mvc to solve the problem?

Comment: asynchronous controller in asp.net mvc is mainly for long running processes such as web service calls,you can use it but it depends on your requirement mainly.I'll prefer queue or relative mechanism such as temporary storage which will get sync with main database once the main database is up.